# Laravel 5 + Homestead + HHVM + PGSQL = Driver not found

Tags: laravel, homestead

My PHP project uses PGSQL. It runs successfully from Homestead on my dev machine. As soon as I add `hhvm: true` to my project in homestead.yaml, and provision -- my web app throws a `PDOException` with a driver is not found. The exception goes away as I remove the `hhvm:true` and re-provision homestead.

Obviously HHVM's config does not include the PGSQL driver.

How do I correct that?

Comment: This should probably be sent as a GitHub issue with Laravel as that should really be bundled...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't give a lot of details about your setup, so it's not clear if you have the Postgres driver installed. Postgres isn't supported right out of the box. You have to build and/or install it yourself.

Facebook has an ["official" list of HHVM extensions](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Extensions). PGSQL is not (yet) integrated into HHVM proper, but Facebook's page points to the external GitHub project, which is here:

[Postgres Extension for HHVM](https://github.com/PocketRent/hhvm-pgsql)

Below is a summary of the project instructions; you can read them yourself in the `README.md` files.

#### Build from source

If you want to build it from source, you will need the hhvm-dev and libpq-dev packages to be installed. Once they have been installed, the following commands will build the extension:

```
$ cd /path/to/source
$ hphpize
$ cmake .
$ make
```

This will produce a pgsql.so file, the dynamically-loadable extension. Copy this file to `/etc/hhvm/pgsql.so`.

#### Pre-built binaries

If you don't want to build it, there are pre-built binary versions for some of the popular distros in the separate "releases" branch here: [Releases](https://github.com/PocketRent/hhvm-pgsql/tree/releases).

Again, copy the downloaded pgsql.so file to `/etc/hhvm/pgsql.so`.

#### Configuration

Whether you build  from source or install binaries, you need to tell HHVM where to find it. Edit your config file (generally `/etc/hhvm/php.ini`) and add these if they're not present:

```
extension_dir = /etc/hhvm
hhvm.extensions[pgsql] = pgsql.so
```

You can check that everything is working by running

```
hhvm --php -r 'var_dump(function_exists("pg_connect"));'
```

If everything is working fine, this will output `bool(true)`.

You may need to restart HHVM to have the server pick up the extension.